Keep only duplicates including original value
I am using the row_number() functon to identify duplicates, partitioned by ID and Name:
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "ID", "Name" ORDER BY "date" ASC) as row_number
from table; 

My data looks like:



ID
Name
date
row_number




1
Name1
2024-11-19
2


1
Name1
2024-11-18
1


2
Name1
2024-11-18
1


3
Name2
2024-11-19
1


4
Name3
2024-11-12
3


4
Name3
2024-11-11
2


4
Name3
2024-11-10
1


10
Name7
2024-11-10
1



Now I want to keep only the rows where we have multiple times the same ID and Name combination.
So the third, fourth and last row should be removed and the output should be as below. How can this be done?



ID
Name
date
row_number




1
Name1
2024-11-19
2


1
Name1
2024-11-18
1


4
Name3
2024-11-12
3


4
Name3
2024-11-11
2


4
Name3
2024-11-10
1




Try count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY "ID","Name") as rows_count and then WHERE rows_count>1

@ValNik Simple and really helpful, thanks.

I would use COUNT() here as a window function, with the same partition as you were using with ROW_NUMBER():
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name) cnt,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY "date") rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, Name, "date", rn
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY ID, "date" DESC;


-- create a table
CREATE TABLE Temp (
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    date DATE,
    row_num INT
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO Temp (ID, Name, date, row_num) VALUES
    (1, 'Name1', '2024-11-19', 2),
    (1, 'Name1', '2024-11-18', 1),
    (2, 'Name1', '2024-11-18', 1),
    (3, 'Name2', '2024-11-19', 1),
    (4, 'Name3', '2024-11-12', 3),
    (4, 'Name3', '2024-11-11', 2),
    (4, 'Name3', '2024-11-10', 1),
    (10, 'Name7', '2024-11-10', 1);

-- query to group
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY date ASC) AS r_num,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Name) AS count_duplicates
    FROM Temp
)
SELECT ID, Name, date, r_num
FROM Data
WHERE count_duplicates > 1
ORDER BY ID, Name, date;



I want to keep only the rows where we have multiple times the same ID and Name combination.


I am using the row_number() function to identify duplicates ...

Well, don't. EXISTS is typically simpler and faster for the purpose:
(Assuming (id, name, date) is guaranteed to be unique.)
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t1
   WHERE  t1.id = t.id
   AND    t1.name = t.name
   AND    t1.date <> t.date  -- or any other suitable column to disambiguate
   );

Especially for big tables with an index on (id, name, date).
Conveniently, a simple SELECT * returns complete original rows out of the box.
